# SF Symbols acting weird with Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, constraints, sf-symbols

I basically have this SF Symbol: `chevron.left`, and I want to get the width and height of this symbol, which I did like this:

```
public func getSize() -> CGSize {
    let size = self.imgView!.size
    return size
}
```

This is how I generate the SF Symbol:

```
UIImage(
   systemName: name,
   withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(textStyle: .title1))?
       .withTintColor(UIColor.TextColor!)
       .withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

I expect the size of the UIImage, which is inside a UIButton to be equal to `UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1).pointSize`, but, instead the height of the SF Symbol is bigger than what I expect it to be.

for `.title1` the height should be 28 points, instead it's 33.3333 points, this is a strange behaviour.

--

*I'm using width and height anchors to constraint the width and the height of the button to the size I receive from `getSize()`

*`contentMode` is equal to `.scaleAspectFit`

*`clipToBounds` is `true`, I've tried with `false` as well, same result.

Comment: See if this answer gives you some insight: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63197816/6257435

Comment: @DonMag that's the issue I'm having... it sucks, why the heck am I setting the pointSize when SF Symbols will change it anyway. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yeah -- SF Symbols are great, but they have their quirks (like many things). I'll go ahead and mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @DonMag in the comments of my post, it's actually an issue with SF Symbols. They've linked an answer(from them in the past), this is the link to that:

[Custom UIImageView is not circle inside custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63189404/custom-uiimageview-is-not-circle-inside-custom-uitableviewcell/63197816#63197816)

All props to them.